# WPF override custom template using trigger XAML tag on validation

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a style for my `TextBox` as shown

```xml
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <!-- ScrollViewer to restore the default textbox template that is gone because of 
                                us now overriding it -->
                            <Border CornerRadius="2" Padding="2" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Gray" />
                            </Border>
                            <ItemsControl FontSize="10" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

When there is an error, I'd like the text box to show a red background, with the error messages appearing underneath it. I've set up a trigger to change the TextBox's background when there's an error, but it seems that since I override the TextBox's normal template so that I can show the error messages, the background of the textbox itself doesn't change (it stays gray). I realize that this is because I used a ScrollViewer to restore the textbox appearance, but now how can I somehow refer to this ScrollViewer from my trigger?

Comment: It is typical for WPF to use Validation.ErrorTemplate for such tasks. Why did you decide to implement it differently?

Comment: @EldHasp It's more for learning purposes. But maybe an argument would be that I'd like to change the style of my default textbox.

Answer (score 0):

> It's more for learning purposes.

You need to better use ControlTemplate.
Possible example:

```xml
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- ScrollViewer to restore the default textbox template that is gone because of 
                        us now overriding it -->
                    <Border x:Name="PART_Border" CornerRadius="2"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ItemsControl FontSize="10" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Validation.Errors}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but now how can I somehow refer to this ScrollViewer from my trigger?

Move the trigger from the `Style` to the `ControlTemplate` and use the `TargetName` property of the `Setter` to refer to the `ScrollViewer` or the parent `Border` element inside the template, e.g.:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border ...>
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Gray" />
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl ... />
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            ...
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```